# Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource : getting this error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

ProductRepository.java

```
package com.example.ecommerce.dao;
    
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.example.ecommerce.entity.Product;


@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    
    Page<Product> findByCategoryId(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Pageable pageable);

}
```

While I am trying to get the category by ID using `RequestParam` but I am getting this error while adding method `findByCategoryId(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Pageable pageable)` in `ProductRepository`.

```
Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)! Reason: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)
    Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)! Reason: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)
    2021-09-16 10:35:48.362  INFO 5104 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2021-09-16 10:35:48.366  INFO 5104 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2021-09-16 10:35:48.385  INFO 5104 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
    2021-09-16 10:35:48.389  INFO 5104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2021-09-16 10:35:48.409  INFO 5104 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
    
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2021-09-16 10:35:48.460 ERROR 5104 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)! Reason: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at com.example.ecommerce.SpringBootEcommerceApplication.main(SpringBootEcommerceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)! Reason: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)! Reason: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository.findByCategoryId(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties$Pageable)
        at 
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonSchemaConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jsonSchemaConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'associationLinks' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'resourceMappings' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.ecommerce.dao.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
```

Can you please explain why am I getting this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue, actually I have imported the wrong package of Pageable class that is import:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebProperties.Pageable;
```

It should be :

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
```

as like the Page class package i.e:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
```